# Dividir 2 valores sacados del Json con AngularJS

Tags: html5, angularjs, json

Tengo otro problema que no sé como hacerlo.

tengo un Json con varios datos y tengo que hacer una media entre 2 datos del json

```
angular.module('playersApp', []).controller("AllPlayerssCtrl", function ($scope) {
$scope.players = [
    {     
        "stats": [
          {
            "name": "goals",
            "value": 5
          },
          {
            "name": "losses",
            "value": 20
          },
          {
            "name": "wins",
            "value": 48
          },
          {
            "name": "draws",
            "value": 23
          },
          {
            "name": "fwd_pass",
            "value": 1533
          },
          {
            "name": "goal_assist",
            "value": 2
          },
          {
            "name": "appearances",
            "value": 80
          },
          {
            "name": "mins_played",
            "value": 6953
          },
          {
            "name": "backward_pass",
            "value": 308
          }
        ]
      },...];
```

Tengo que mostrar por ventana la media de goles por partido, es decir, dividir el value de goals entre el value de mins_played y no sé como hacer la función sacando dichos valores del json y de ahi en el ng-if del html llamar a dicha función para mostrar el resultado.

Si me podeis ayudar por favor os lo agradecería.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Pública el html para ver cómo la función que mencionas? Y donde está el valor mins_played? No está en el json que públicas

Comment: en el json están { "name": "goals","value": 5}, y mas abajo {"name":"mins_played","value": 6953}, y la funcion que quiero hacer es dividir esos 2 values y mostrar el valor de la división por ventana, que me imagino que será poniendo un ng-if="nombreFuncion()" en el div correspondiente del HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function MyController($scope) {

  $scope.players = [{
      "stats": [{
          "name": "goals",
          "value": 5
        },
        {
          "name": "losses",
          "value": 20
        },
        {
          "name": "wins",
          "value": 48
        },
        {
          "name": "draws",
          "value": 23
        },
        {
          "name": "fwd_pass",
          "value": 1533
        },
        {
          "name": "goal_assist",
          "value": 2
        },
        {
          "name": "appearances",
          "value": 80
        },
        {
          "name": "mins_played",
          "value": 6953
        },
        {
          "name": "backward_pass",
          "value": 308
        }
      ]
    },

    
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.players.length; i++) {
    for (var x=0; x< $scope.players[i].stats.length; x++) {
      switch($scope.players[i].stats[x].name) {
        case 'goals':
         var tmp_goals = $scope.players[i].stats[x].value;
        break;
        case 'mins_played':
         var tmp_mins = $scope.players[i].stats[x].value;
        break;
        
      }
      
    }
    
    $scope.players[i].media = tmp_goals/tmp_mins;


  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyController">

  <div ng-repeat="jugador in players">

    <p>
      <p>
        {{(jugador.media) | number:4}}

  </div>

</div>
```

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, unas mas elegantes que otras, yo usaría esta que te planteo, en la que saco los datos que me interesan del array, los proceso, y meto el resultado en una clave nueva.

Si mañana necesitas mostrar algún dato mas de la estadística, por ejemplo asistencias por minuto jugado, metes en el switch **goal_assist**, haces el calculo sobre `$scope.players[i].media_asistencia = tmp_goals_assist/tmp_mins` y luego pintas por pantalla `jugador.media_asistencia`

Comment: si, tb tengo que hacer la media de pases por minuto, y ya teniendo una ya sabria como hacer la otra. Muchas gracias